# How to map objects (DTO) on client side?

Tags: angular, typescript, automapper, aspnetboilerplate, dto-mapping

- Typescript
- ABP + .NET Core

I'm using a grid to insert rows (the grid I'm using is a component of the DevExtreme framework). Anyway, similar to other grids, it raises `onRowInserting` events when the records are inserted, providing the inserted row as a parameter. I need to convert that "anonymous" object (the inserted data) to my client-side DTO in this event.

```
onRowInserting(e) {
    let mynewrow: ItemDto = e.data; // e.data contains the inserted row
}
```

To better understand what I need to achieve, please read this post:

[Add rows to DevExtreme grid (angular) - model/schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48792532/add-rows-to-devextreme-grid-angular-model-schema)

## EDIT

The `ItemDto`:

```
export class ItemDto implements IItemDto {
    description: string;
    note: string;
    quantita: number;
    postId: number;
    id: number;

    constructor(data?: IItemDto) {
        if (data) {
            for (var property in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(property))
                    (<any>this)[property] = (<any>data)[property];
            }
        }
    }

    init(data?: any) {
        if (data) {
            this.description = data["description"];
            this.note = data["note"];
            this.quantita = data["quantita"];
            this.postId = data["postId"];
            this.id = data["id"];
        }
    }

    static fromJS(data: any): ItemDto {
        let result = new ItemDto();
        result.init(data);
        return result;
    }

    toJSON(data?: any) {
        data = typeof data === 'object' ? data : {};
        data["description"] = this.description;
        data["note"] = this.note;
        data["quantita"] = this.quantita;
        data["postId"] = this.postId;
        data["id"] = this.id;
        return data; 
    }

    clone() {
        const json = this.toJSON();
        let result = new ItemDto();
        result.init(json);
        return result;
    }
}

export interface IItemDto {
    description: string;
    note: string;
    quantita: number;
    postId: number;
    id: number;
}
```

And below, the content of `e.data` (at this moment, I've added only some columns to the grid, so not all fields are present).

```
Object {
    __KEY__: "7c2ab8-1ff6-6b53-b9d7-ba25c27"
    description: "mydescription"
    id: 32
    note: "mynote"
    postId: 4
    quantita: 2
     >  __proto__: Object { constructor; , _defineG....
}
```

This image represents the object better: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkEB1.jpg

I'm not sure what I did in the line `let mynewrow: ItemDto`.
I don't know if it is correct, or if it is enough to use the variable later, passing it to the service that saves the new row.

Comment: Can you please post `ItemDto` class structure and `e.data` value in your question.

Comment: Are you getting any problems with the code you supplied Alex? If so, please tell us what the problem is.

Comment: @viveknuna i've added them to the post

Comment: you can set create a new object of your class type and set the individual properties to the corresponding e.data properties.

Comment: @viveknuna manually? no way to automate this operation? like happens serverside thanks to automapper?

Answer (score 1):

You can use decorators and serializers. See lib for ts here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialize-ts

Answer (score 1):

How about using `object.assign()` to push the values of the properties from your JSON response object into the class you want?

```js
class thingy {
  a = null;
  print = function() {
    console.log(this.a);
  };
}

const sourceJson = { 
  a: "hello world" 
};

const target = Object.assign(new thingy(), sourceJson);

target.print()
```