# How to use Automapper in Typescript?

Tags: mapping, automapper

Are there any packages available for mapping two object in typescript I.E Automapper? I found a couple of packages but they don't have enough document for implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to map objects (DTO) on client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48802922/how-to-map-objects-dto-on-client-side)

Comment: No, It is different.

Answer (score 8):

Here are a couple I am aware of:

- https://github.com/loedeman/AutoMapper (https://www.npmjs.com/package/automapper-ts)
- https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer

There is also a good discussion about this at https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/4tg69t/question_typescript_auto_mapping/ that might be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it seems https://github.com/loedeman/AutoMapper is not well-maintained. As of answering your question, it has not been updated since 2017.

While digging through the "Issues" section I found a well-maintained fork: https://github.com/nartc/mapper

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at

- [mpr the object mapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dboneslabs/mpr) - for Typescript and JavaScript
- [Docs are here](https://bitbucket.org/dboneslabs/mpr/wiki/Home)

Disclaimer I'm the author, I wrote it as I wanted some more of the advanced options (note it flexible with how classes are detailed and mapped)

Comment: This site can’t be reached

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dboneslabs/mpr

Comment: updated the link in the post